# Tree grid component with cellTemplate in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treegrid

I am using tree-grid component in AngularJS: http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html

here is above example in plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/CQwY0sNh3jcLLc0vMP5D?p=preview
```

in comparison with ng-grid, I can't define `cellTemplate`, but I really need cell formatting possibility. How can I implement example rules for each row:

- if `TimeZone` is equal to `EST` color `Description` content on green
- if `TimeZone` is equal to `PST` color `Description` content on red
- if `Population` as an odd number replace `Area` content  by image `good.jpg`
- if `Population` as a even number replace `Area` content by image `bad.jpg`

with `tree-grid-directive`?

Maybe you can propose me some other AngularJS component (with tree expand functionality)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adapt-strap has a component called tree-browser. That is what you are looking for.
It is highly customizable and you can specify template for the whole row. You can also submit a feature request if something is missing.

Project homepage and examples: http://adaptv.github.io/adapt-strap/

Comment: Thanks, it looks like something what I was looking for! But I have problem with template for whole row. I would like to add new column with uppercase name: http://jsfiddle.net/t2qafj81/ How to do this correctly?

Comment: You can add as many columns as u want. You won the row template. You just have to set width for each cell using css. Give each cell some class and do min-width in css. so that way it will look like a table.